# Cannot connect to openssh using otp ssh module

Tags: ssh, erlang, openssh, erlang-otp

I'm trying to use erlang ssh module to connect to openssh (version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-6) server.
OpenSSH server **uses default configuration**

Doing the following:

```
ssh:connect(Server, 22, [MyFancyOptions])
```

Gives:

```
Selection of key exchange algorithm failed
```

Indeed, by watching Wireshark I saw that key exchange algorithms proposed by erlang client:

```
diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

and server:

```
curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```

do not match...

Question:
Is there any way to connect to the ssh server in erlang?

PS. Yes I saw

```
%% TODO: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 should also be supported.
%% Maybe check more things ...
verify_algorithm(#alg{kex = 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'}) ->
```

But do not tell me that the holy Erlang cannot handle modern ssh...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks as though you need to augment your server to offer the extra KexAlgorithms, so something like:

> KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

BUT... Having done this I'm not succeeding in doing anything useful. I see an error in the logs:

> sshd[8026]: dispatch_protocol_error: type 30 seq 7

So it seems Erlang ssh module has some significant issues with modern ssh...

Answer (score 0):

Erlang ssh client in OTP 15 will work with openssh-6.7 server if you configure openssh to openssh6.0 defaults in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, like this:

```
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour
KexAlgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Erlang ssh client only supports ciphers aes128-cbc,3des-cbc which are not enabled by default in openssh-6.7, at least not in Debian openssh package.